# Can I power my rpi with netgear WNDR3700v5 router?

Tags: usb, power

I currently own a netgear WNDR3700v5 router which has 1x usb port and I was wondering if I would be able to power my rpi (Pi 2 Model B) + 2.5" external HDD with it. The PSU for the router is 12v 1.5A. I can't really measure how much the router is really using so I was wondering if anyone has experience with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried with my Belkin N600 with usb but that did not work well for me. The input for my router was 12V/1 amp.

The easiest way you can check it is try connecting a mobile device to the setup. If it says slow charging then its also likely that your raspberry will also have issues, with performance especially.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a router isn't made to give power supply for a "big" device like Raspberry pi...

Answer (score 0):

USB ports are typically limited to 500mA. This is typically insufficient for a RPi2, especially if the HDD is powered by the Pi.